# Use Ajax to show progress of a PHP script called by another Ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, get, progress, simultaneous

I make a jQuery Ajax call to a PHP script that runs for a decent amount of time (between 1- seconds and 3 minutes).  It constantly logs a percentage of completion in a database.  How can I continually run another Ajax request at the same to report the percentage complete from the MySQL database to the user?

**EDIT**
I understand how to use a separate PHP script to query the database, so my question is more how to set up the JavaScript and Ajax calls

Comment: You might consider [Gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/gearman.examples-reverse-bg.php) as an alternative for the background process. It also provides an interface for job progress, so you won't need the MySQL database for this: [GearmanJob::sendStatus()](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanjob.sendstatus.php) and [GearmanClient::jobStatus()](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.jobstatus.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your AJAX call to kick off your process, you could make another AJAX call in a loop which requests, returns, and presents the current  percentage complete until it reaches 100%. Basically, one AJAX call to initiate the process and then a series of calls which check status.

Update: Here is some simple JavaScript to achieve what you want:

```
<script>
function startProcess() {
    //start your long-running process
    $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'GET',
                url: "/longRunningProcess",
                async: true,
                success:
                    function (data) {
                        //do something - your long process is finished
                    }
            });
}
function getStatus() {
    //check your progress
    $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'GET',
                url: "/checkProgress",
                async: true,
                success:
                    function (data) {
                        //assume the data returned in the percentage complete
                        var percentage = parseInt(data);

                        //write your status somewhere, like a jQuery progress bar?

                        if (percentage < 100) {
                            //if not complete, check again
                            getStatus();
                        }
                    }
            });
}
```

Comment: WHat kind of loop would this be in?  Would it be a an Ajax loop (the progress call) within a while loop (keeps running the progress call running) within an Ajax loop (that calls the PHP script that's being monitored)?

Comment: I've added some sample code to show you what I mean. Basically, initiate the process through Ajax, check the status from another Ajax call and keep calling until your status is done.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this would not work with sessions as the second PHP script would not be able to open the session... so your check progress should have all it needs to check status without opening session.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need another URL to call that polls progress from the database.
In other words, a different PHP script that reports progress.
The Ajax call will probably use timeout or whatever fancy stuff jQuery has to schedule itself periodically (until the server call reports completion).

Remember to handle exceptional cases where the server side processing dies (and thus never completes!)

Comment: Hm, thinking now, you might want to use exec to run the actual long running process and immediately return result to the first ajax call. Remember that your browser probably limits outstanding Ajax calls to the same domain to two....